# Bash - check for a string in file path

Tags: bash, jenkins, filepath, slash

How can I check for a string in a file path in bash? I am trying:

```
if [[$(echo "${filePathVar}" | sed 's#//#:#g#') == *"File.java"* ]]
```

to replace all forward slashes with a colon (:) in the path. It's not working. Bash is seeing the file path string as a file path and throws the error "No such file or directory". The intention is for it to see the file path as a string.

Example: filePathVar could be

> **/myloc/src/File.java

in which case the check should return true.

*Please note that I am writing this script inside a Jenkins job as a build step.*

`Updates as of 12/15/15`

The following returns `Not found`, which is wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash
sources="**/src/TESTS/A.java **/src/TESTS/B.java"

if [[ "${sources}" = ~B.java[^/]*$ ]];
then
echo "Found!!"
else
echo "Not Found!!"
fi
```

The following returns `Found` which also also wrong (removed the space around the comparator `=`).

```
#!/bin/bash
sources="**/src/TESTS/A.java **/src/TESTS/C.java"

if [[ "${sources}"=~B.java[^/]*$ ]];
then
echo "Found!!"
else
echo "Not Found!!"
fi
```

The comparison operation is clearly not working.

Comment: Replace all forward slashes with colon: `${filePathVar//\//.}`. But why do you want to do that?

Comment: `'s#//#:#g#'` has double forward slash...

Comment: Please see updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked in a simpler way as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
sources="**/src/TESTS/A.java **/src/TESTS/B.java"
if [[ $sources == *"A.java"* ]]
then
echo "Found!!"
else
echo "Not Found!!"
fi
```

Comment: In this code, the variable `sources` will _always_ contain the text `A.java`.  Note also that _pathname expansion_ is suppressed inside `[[...]]`.  Consequently, this code will always return `Found!!`.

Comment: The variable sources actually gets it value from somewhere else, and the string assigned to it varies. I just gave an example.

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to use bash's builtin regex matching facility:

```
$ filePathVar=/myLoc/src/File.java
if [[ "$filePathVar" =~ File.java[^/]*$ ]]; then echo Match; else echo No Match; fi
Match
```

Inside `[[...]]`, the operator `=~` does regex matching.  The regular expression `File.java[^/]*` matches any string that contains `File.java` optionally followed by anything except `/`.

Comment: Thanks @John1024. It still does not work within the context of Jenkins and throws an error saying "No such file or directory". I want the comparison to happen purely as a String context with no file or directory evaluation being made by Bash.

Comment: @naspras My goal was for this to work for you under bash.  I see that you added to the question that this is to be done "inside a Jenkins job as a build step."  Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Jenkins.  Is the error you are getting a Jenkins error or a bash error?

Comment: it is a bash error. Jenkins executes the script purely as a shell script.

Comment: In that case, can you show me the full and complete error message?

Comment: sorry for the delay in response. The full error message is: `[[**/myloc/src/File.java: No such file or directory`. The code is `if [["${filePathVar}" =~ File.java[^/]*$]]; then ...`

Comment: It worked! I had to add a space between the "[[" and the command. Thanks! +1

Comment: Sorry, it did not work. Please see updates on main posting.

Comment: @naspras Both of the codes in the update have serious problems.  The first one has a space between `=` and `~` that should not be there and is also missing a space after the `~`.  The second is missing spaces around `=~`.  If you are going to use `bash`, you have to be careful with spaces.  The spacing in my answer above is correct.